# implementing full screen is covering only 70% of screen

Tags: css

When I click on button my full screen is as below

```
|---------------|
|---------------|
|---------------|
|               | horizontal scroll
|               |
|               |
|               |
```

Problem is it occupying only 80% of the screen only even though it has enough data to cover.

my css class

```
.full-screen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 700;
  background: white;
}
```

Please guide.

Comment: Put your code in a working jsFiddle or something similar, it's very hard to tell what's the actual issue

Comment: @Anzeo the application is very big, if i put some portion of code in jsfiddle, it is working without any issue.

Comment: If you cant provide the code that is making trouble, we cant help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `position:fixed;`, you can do this, to fill out the screen:

```
.full-screen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: 700;
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: I have position:fixed in css.
Still it is not covering full screen

Comment: Remove the width and min-height and add right:0; and bottom:0; is what I have done in the answer. That should do it

Comment: Then it it some of your other code that is the problem. It works fine, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lon71z4q/